# Android TextView with multiple lines

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I want a TextView that should be broken into 4 lines. For e.g.

```
Vishal Vyas
  Having
   342
Reputation
```

Note, the gravity should be `center_horizontal`

I tried following :

```
<TextView
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/lblUserRep"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="4"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:text="VishalVyas Having 342 Reputation" >
</TextView>
```

This works! but produces following output:

```
VishalVyas
  Having
   342
Reputation
```

**Problems:**

1. It doesn't work with the space between words Vishal and Vyas.
2. `android:layout_width="70dp"` is harcoded and there can be any name with n number of characters instead of `VishalVyas`.

Please advice.

**Added:**
It would be fine if I need to write a custom `TextView` for achieving this but I'll require some guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just curious... you do have a space between Vishal Vyas in your actual code (point 1 mentions that the space isn't rendered, but I don't see a space)?

Comment: @DavidDraughn actually I needed a text view with a fixed four lines and if I put space between Vishal and Vyas in this statement like `android:text="Vishal Vyas Having 342 Reputation"`, some times the word "Reputation" was not displayed because it was shifted to the 5th line.

Comment: I figured out that when wrap_content is set it doesn't transform into multiple lines, but you need to have match_parent, or maxWidth with wrap_content.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think it's wrapping because "Vishal Vyas" is going beyond 70dp.  Instead, do `wrap_content` on the width and use newline characters for lines instead of wrapping (i.e. "Vishal Vyas\n342\nReputation")

Comment: Actually I tried this before was confused by looking at `Graphical Layout` mode in eclipse. It was displaying like this `Vishal Vyas\nHaving\n342\nReputation`.

But it worked like a charm when I ran the application on actual device and emulator.

Comment: That's actually interesting to know.  I've never hardcoded text into a TextView like that.  It's usually a string resource ID.  I wonder why it wouldn't decipher newline characters like that.

Comment: Yeah, I tried with a string resource ID and this time `Graphical Layout` displayed correct output. So from now on wards I'll never use hardcoded text.. It was good school time lesson to learn. Thanks once again ;)

Comment: Can the Text="lots of text" be split over more than one line in the xml file?
e.g. (+ doesn't work, is there something that does?)
Text="Line 1"
+ "Line 2"

Answer (score 14):

You should be able to insert the newline character `\n` to control where the splits go. Once you do that, you can expand your `TextView` wider so that it can accommodate a longer user name but still break in the right place.

Answer (score 8):

```
android:lines="2"
android:minLines="2"
android:singleLine="false"
```

Even if Android Studio warns that `android:singleLine=false` is deprecated, keep it and one can have the number of lines they want for their text box depending on the length of their text

Answer (score 1):

I did so:

The Container of TextView:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

The TextView:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Then,

The Text of the TextView was showed in two lines or more...