# 2 TextView multilines in android

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-edittext

I want to make quiz app. I have two Textview and one edit text.

I placed the edittext between two textview.

[image: layout]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"  />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/second_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:lines="6"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCheckAnswer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check" />

</LinearLayout>
```

how to make text from the second textview below first textview?

I want to make the words "Nijuu sai desu. Chugoku desu." below "Watashi wa".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android TextView with multiple lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843891/android-textview-with-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 0):

**try**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/first_question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/second_question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="6"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/first_question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="18sp"  />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
         <TextView
           android:id="@+id/second_question"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:singleLine="false"
           android:lines="6"
           android:textSize="20sp" />
   </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCheckAnswer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check" />

</LinearLayout>
```